# About pytorch, I can't understand why that's the output

Tags: python, pytorch

The code is as below about pytorch, it's about derivative, I think the output is 18 but it's 4.5, I don'k know why:

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()
out.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

The output:
tensor([[4.5000, 4.5000],
[4.5000, 4.5000]])

```
I think the derivative is 2*3*(1+2), so it should be: 
tensor([[18, 18],
        [18, 18]])
```

Why the output is 4.5?
Some people think it's the mean method that make the derivative /4, but when I do the code "print(out)", the output is "tensor(27., grad_fn=)" rather than (4.5., grad_fn=), I'm a new learning of pytorch, so I don't know what it does with "tensor.mean()", but since the output of "print(out)" is 27, so I don't think there is a "/4" process in "tensor.mean()", so I don't think it should include "/4" process in the derivative computation, is that correct?(Please help me~)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I think it goes:

`y = x + 2` and `z = y * y * 3`,
so z is `3 * (x+2)^2`

Next, `out = z.mean()`, or `sigma z / n` which is `sigma z/4` since we had a total of 4 numbers in z.

Thus, you find the derivative of sigma `(3 * (x + 2)^2)/4` at x = 1.
That gives `(3/4) * 2(x + 2)` at x = 1, which is 4.5

So I think you had it all figured out, except that in the last step you missed dividing by 4, which you need to do since there's a mean() function in there.

Edit:
Since you're confused with how the mean() is affecting the output, let's do a tensor of values [1,2,3,4] instead of `torch.ones()` to see the effect.

```
x = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()
out.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

this will output

```
tensor([4.5000, 6.0000, 7.5000, 9.0000])
```

How? Remember we derived the equation for our derivative to be:
`(3/4) * 2(x + 2)`

 Now you substitute x to be 1, and get 4.500.

 Then for x = 2, you get 6.000, for x = 3 you get 7.500 and so on.

In the earlier example, you had four instances of x = 1 which is why you had x.grad to be [[4.5, 4.5], [4.5, 4.5]]

Comment: But I think mean means mean of all 4 numbers in that tensor, which is 27 of 27,27,27,27,  so mean is not 27/4, but 27, is that right?

Comment: When I do "print(out)", the output is "tensor(27., grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)" rather than 27/4, so I didn't think about doing /4 in the derivative process, what's the mechanism in it? @Ayush

Comment: @XianglongChen note that Z was a tensor of four 27 values, (27,27,27,27). When we do a .mean() on it, it sums up over all values and divides by the number of elements. So (27 + 27 + 27 + 27)/4 which equals 27, which is what out is.

Comment: But if it's (27+27+27+27)/4, then the derivative should be 3*2*(1+2)/4, which is 4.5 rather than ([[4.5000, 4.5000], [4.5000, 4.5000]]), is that correct?@Ayush  But the output of "print(x.grad)" is "tensor([[4.5000, 4.5000],
        [4.5000, 4.5000]])", that's what make me wonder.

Comment: @XianglongChen That's how grad works, we obtained the derivative equation and substituted the value of x(which was 1) four times(since x has 4 values, and you need to update each one of them, that's how backpropagation works). I've edited my answer to illustrate that with an example.

Comment: thank you@Ayush for editing. but on my mac, the code "x = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()
out.backward()
print(x.grad)",  the ourput of your code is "None" and I don't know why.

Comment: @XianglongChen I have no idea why that's the case, I'm using the latest version of PyTorch. I just ran the code on Colab and here's the output: https://snipboard.io/JelVKh.jpg

Comment: I fixed it and now everything is OK, thank you very much, it's very helpful~@Ayush